# redirect wordpress calls to a page

Tags: redirect, wordpress

I'm not really sure what is the best way to do this. Say you have set up a page like so:

```
www.myblog.com/page1
```

Is it possible to, specify that the request to any of the subpages under page1 be redirected to a single page? Say if I had page1.php as one of my pages, any URL that is prefixed with:

```
www.myblog.com/page1/...
```

wordpress would use that file to generate the page.

Basically, I have some custom content that I want fetched with php, and it depends on which subpage is being loaded. The format of the custom content is always the same, only the 'arguments' differ. Is there a way to do this within Wordpress? And if not, where should I should I start looking to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try modifying .htaccess file and rewriting url so all requests for /page1/page2 will be rewrite to /page1=?page=page2 or something like that

Comment: excellent suggestion. are there ideas for less 'hardcoded' solutions thought?