# How to map an arbitrary URL to a function in a Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a Wordpress plugin that redirects visitors of example.com/redirect/XXX to a different page based on the value of XXX. I think I know how to do the redirect logic, but I don't know how to make sure that my Wordpress plugin function will be called when a visitor goes to example.com/redirect. Right now I just get a 404. There are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499914/redirect-wordpress-calls-to-a-page) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785840/how-does-wordpress-rewrite-the-url-without-a-rewrite-map) that involved changing the .htaccess file, but I want this to function as a standalone plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I need this kind of things i just create a common page with template as the "plugin", a page with all the functions that I need.

For example, if i need a shopping cart, I just create a cart.php as:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Cart
*/
// functions here
?>
```

And I go to my wp-admin and create a page with Cart as its template.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do which is quite vague ( when you say page you actually mean page ? post ? cpt ? and when you say plugin functions - what are they ? and do you use permalinks ?) 
.. but under some conditions you could use [wp conditionals](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) .

example ( from codex )

```
    is_singular( 'foo' ) 
   // Returns true if the post_type is "foo". execute plugin hook
    is_singular( array( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ) ) 
   // Returns true if the post_type is "foo", "bar", or "baz".
   // See also the Custom Post Types book.
```

or if you aim at filtering you can always hook to `pre_get_post` with `is_main_query()` or any other conditional //